# How to create a sequence in Postgresql with periodic auto reset?

Tags: postgresql, sequence

I have a requirement where I need to create a sequence that can auto reset periodically,  let's say on each new year.
The sequence will be used in a table for composed ID.

Comment: Create a cron job that runs `setval()` at the desired interval

Comment: not an option for my case

Comment: What _a_horse_with_no_name_ suggested is clearly the first thing that springs to ones mind. Would you please tell us why that's no option in your case? Meaning, giving us the whole story as there seems to be more dependency.

Comment: Any action done againyst the database must happen from inside postgres , cron runs at OS level. That's my condition.

Comment: Well, then bad news: See http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/43937/how-to-run-recurring-tasks-on-a-postgresql-database-without-a-cron-like-tool. No hint on a change for the better so far.

Comment: "*Any action done againyst the database must happen from inside postgres*" - that's impossible. You always need an external program to perform "any action against the database, e.g. psql to run a SQL statement manually or your application. You **always** have some "external" tool that "does the action". If you are not allowed to use an external program there is no way you can use the database.